# How to take STDOUT and display it in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, shell

I have this code, which should spawn a child process. I want to send the information (stdout) to an html label to display it. How can I go about this? Here is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('stdout: ${data}');
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('stderr: ${data}');
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log('child process exited with code ${code}');
});

 </script>
```

Comment: You can't run this code in a browser

Comment: What you could do thought, is save stdout in a variable, and expose a html page in which you include that variable. Look at Express and `ejs`.

Comment: Yeah, I was actually trying to get this to work in Sails JS which uses express and ejs. I got tired of trying to figure out how to do it (doesn't seem to be a lot of docs on this subject) so I just went with a straight HTML text file with javascript in-line to see if that would work. I'm not having luck either way, but I'll keep looking into that on Sails.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I'm ecstatic to hear this so I can stop banging my head against the wall trying to figure it out and look for a different solution, but I got to ask, what about this makes it impossible to run in a browser?